# How can i get the applicationiconbar button and click it automatically for windows phone 7 ui automation test?

Tags: windows-phone-7, automated-tests, ui-automation

I understand that 'ApplicationIconBar' can not derive from 'System.Windows.Controls'.

I cannot find the automation interface for  'ApplicationIconBar'.

How can I find the button on it and  click it automatically?

Comment: I've no idea why people downvote a valid question.

Comment: Nor do I - so I added an upvote for balance ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are automating your UI.

If you are using the expensify toolkit then the only way I've found to do this is to use touch gestures using mouse manipulation - but obviously this only works on the phone.

If you are using some hand crafted toolkit, then you might need to use some wrapper around the  application bar in the same way that the binding application bars do. This isn't quite UI automation (it's not automationpeer level) but the application bar is not a standard silverlight control, and this hack will at least allow you to progress.

Comment: Thanks for your advise,and Can I write a class 'MyapplicationBarIconButton' derive from 'Button',and I can not add it to ApplicationBar.Buttons.what should I do for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyApplicationBarIconButton : Button, IApplicationBarIconButton
    {
        public MyApplicationBarIconButton()
        {    
        }
        public MyApplicationBarIconButton(Uri iconUri,String text)
        {
            IconUri = iconUri;
            Text = text;
        }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public  event EventHandler Click;
        public Uri IconUri { get; set; }
        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    }
```